# MVT : Integration of harmonic function over boundary of a disc

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

$u$ is a harmonic function in a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ and 
$ u : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$
suppose $\bar{D{(a,R)}}$$ \subset \Omega $
then To show that $u(a) = \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\int \int_{\bar{D{(a,R)}}}u(x,y)dxdy$

My attempt. I took a function $f$ and parametrized the boundary of the disc. Integrating over the boundary by using Cauchy integral formula, I get

$f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(a+Re^{1\theta})d\theta$

How should I proceed further. I know this is mean value theorem but I am stuck here.

Please help !

Comment: Oh, I see...$a$ is a point.  Sorry.

Comment: $a \in \mathbb{C}$.  I was a little confused, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but haven't quite been general enough. You used the Cauchy integral formula to get to
$$ 2\pi f(a) = \int_0^{2\pi} f(a+Re^{i\theta}) \, d\theta, $$
but this is also true for any disc of radius $0<r<R$, i.e.
$$ 2\pi f(a) = \int_0^{2\pi} f(a+re^{i\theta}) \, d\theta, \tag{1} $$
Now, we have a series of integrals over circles, and want to turn them into an integral over a disc. The area element is $r \, dr$, because each circle has length $r$, so the area of the small annulus between them is
$$ \pi (r+h)^2-\pi r^2 = \pi(2rh+h^2) \sim 2\pi rh $$
as $h \to 0$. (we divide this by $2\pi$ now as we've already integrated over the angles) So the integral over the disc will be found by multiplying both sides of (1) by $r$ and integrating from $0$ to $R$:
$$ 2\pi f(a) \int_0^R r \, dr = \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} f(a+re^{i\theta}) r \, d\theta \, dr. $$

The left hand side is $\pi R^2 f(a)$, and the right hand side is the integral over the disc $|z-a|<R$, which is equivalent to what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Alot. for this detailed explanation. I managed to solve it few hours back but your answer will help others in future.